# Gaining sqlite3 functionality in C (Eclipse)

Tags: c, sqlite, arm, linker-errors

I would like to be able to use the sqlite3 functionality with C, I recently downloaded the sqlite3 amalgamation from the SQLite website and compiled this to get sqlite3.so and hence included this in my project. I have included what I believe to be the necessary libraries to compile the code however I always get the same error. The linker appears to be looking in the wrong folder for -lsqlite3 and I cant find this specified path anywhere in any of the project properties and it also does not appear to be a valid location on my PC!
Below is the output when I try to compile the code. If I am stupidly missing anything required for any help please let me know, bit of a beginner when using eclipse for C.

```
16:21:03 **** Build of configuration Debug for project SQLite ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
Finished building: ../main.c

Building target: SQLite
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/root/workspacecpp/SQLite/ -o "SQLite"  ./main.o   -lsqlite3.so

/home/development/raspberrypi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3.so

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SQLite] Error 1
```

Comment: Posting what you can post as text as image is discouraged.

Comment: You using Linux? If yes, which distribution?

Comment: I am using Linux Mint on Ubuntu 14.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cross-compiling, so you need to place the ARM[*] version of libsqlite3.so in a place where the cross compiler will look for it. This is likely somewhere in or below `/home/development/raspberrypi/tools/arm-bcm2708/`. See your cross-compiler's documentation.

[*] Of course you used your cross-compiler to create an **ARM** version of libsqlite3.so :-)

Comment: Is there a difference between libsqlite3.so and sqlite3.so? As I have placed sqlite3.so in the folder that the linker looks in however it still cannot find it and I get the same error

Comment: The linker should be looking for lib<whatever>.so